# $wpdb->query can't insert data

Tags: database, query, wpdb

I Write Code to Save data in the Wordpress database table (table name is wp_fafa)

But Can't Save data in

```
$qry = $wpdb->query( "INSERT INTO `wp_fafa` (titile,liveprice,changing,lowest,topest,time) VALUES ('" . trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue) . "','" . trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue) . "','" . trim($row->item(4)->nodeValue) . "','" . trim($row->item(6)->nodeValue) . "','" . trim($row->item(8)->nodeValue) . "','" . trim($row->item(10)->nodeValue) . "')");
$wpdb->query($qry);
```

Comment: why do you use `query` method and not `insert`?

Comment: Because I want after save data .. update they with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will properly store data in `wp_fafa`:

```
$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'fafa', 
    array( 
        'title'     => trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue),
        'liveprice' => trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue),
        'changing'  => trim($row->item(4)->nodeValue),
        'lowest'    => trim($row->item(6)->nodeValue),
        'topest'    => trim($row->item(8)->nodeValue),
        'time'      => trim($row->item(10)->nodeValue)   
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s'
    ) 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have declared the $wpdb variable `global $wpdb;`. Also calling `$wpdb->query()` will execute the query for you, so no need to do it again.

I would also recommend using `$wpdb->insert()` as this escapes your data for you:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert(
    $wpdb->prefix . 'fafa',
    array(
        'titile'    => trim( $row->item(0)->nodeValue ),
        'liveprice' => trim( $row->item(2)->nodeValue ),
        'changing'  => trim( $row->item(4)->nodeValue ),
        'lowest'    => trim( $row->item(6)->nodeValue ),
        'topest'    => trim( $row->item(8)->nodeValue ),
        'time'      => trim( $row->item(10)->nodeValue ),
    )
);
```

Comment: not working .. I use wpdb->prefix . 'fafa', 
///   array(  // then work @mikemanager

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed out the $wpdb->prefix from my example. I have edited my answer. :)

Comment: ok. know how can i update all fields in your code with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ? @mikemanger